# Get the running instance of VersionControlServer(tfs 2015) from Visual Studio 2015 to bind a GettingEventHandler to it

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015, vsix, tfs-2015

I want to scan all XML-Files that have been checked out of the Server.

```
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt project =
        dte.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt") as
            Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt.Project;
```

I tried this. But i get a NullPointerException.

I'm looking for something thats triggers an event or something. On Serverside there is the ISubscriber interface.

The dte object isnt working either cause it hast no event trigger.

----edit---

There is a "GettingEventHandler" in Tfs.client Package. I can bind things together but i need the VersionControlServer Instance running in Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Are you looking for https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx?

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, but it is not really helping. In all clienside Examples there is a new VersionControlServer instance running. I want to use the one that is already running in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read over that all Events from TFS are crossinstance. I just started a new instance and attached my eventhandler to it. It works great.

```
        tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(serveradressename));
        versionControl = (VersionControlServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
        versionControl.Getting += new GettingEventHandler(ScanAllNewDocs);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can also install the [TFS 2015 power tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1).

You can find files that under version control by status by selecting File -- Source Control -- Find -- Find by Status, then you can find all checked out files in the path you select.